# Django model changes

Tags: python, mysql, django

I haven't been able to figure out the answer by google-fu, and I'm a little baffled. I'm trying to help a friend get some code up and running and ran into a bit of trouble while trying to change the model for a database item. This is Django 1.7, python 3.1, and mysql.

In the beginning they had a column of type varchar with a size of 1 and it specified a default value of L. Later they changed the model to a size of 6 with a default of NOPREF. When running migrate with that change it would error out, saying that the default was invalid. Going into the database and increasing the size of the column dispenses with the error, but struck me as mysterious enough that I thought I'd ask here as to what might be going on.

Now, I'm very new to Django and not terribly experienced with python, so this next question may be a bit dumb. When constructing the model does the default value get stored in the database, or is it just used within the python object? I ask because changing the default value in code doesn't seem to alter it in the table.

Thanks!

Comment: This is unrelated to your question, but note that Python 3.1 is not supported on Django 1.7. ["It works with Python 2.7, 3.2 or 3.3."](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/install/).

Comment: Django does not store the default value in the database schema so if the value is in the schema it could account for the error you experienced.

Comment: Whoops, I meant python 3.41, sorry. What about the size of a field? The error comes in because the suggested default value is greater in length than the field as it was initially declared, but the model was also updated to the correct size. If I go in and resize it manually there's no error.